# Using 1 usb barcode scanner on 2 computers

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, c#-3.0, barcode-scanner, emulation

I have been doing some research but I can't find a solution for my specific problem.

We have an ancient program at work that works as a stock manager. 
Now I need to build extra features but I can't use the SQL database used by that system. (kafka was here)

So I started building a program that runs parallel to the existing system. 
To reduce the extra input I want to use the same input devices. 
These are mainly barcode scanners, which if I'm correct, are basically just keyboard emulators.

The question: Is there a way to use 1 Usb device on multiple computers?

I was thinking to hook the scanner to the computer where I can do the most and let this computer act as an emulator for the other computer? 
But I think that's as realistic as an usb splitter.

On the other hand I was thinking of using a raspberry or arduino is "the middle man" between the scanner and 2 pc's which should give me more options.

Extra difficulties:

- I can't install anything on the computers that run the ancient program.
- I have little to no rights on other computers I can use (kafka, you again?)
- I can only work with C#3.5 to avoid triggering the overly sensitive virus detection :)
- I can't set up servers
- I can only run stuff in windows
- I can't run installers